# files wont upload to server

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

Hi I am having trouble uploading files to my server, they enter the database fine and the path is correct but for some reason the files just wont go in.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach ($_FILES['ppt']['name'] AS $name) {
        $i = 1;
        $ppt = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $name.$i));
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $data = array(
            'eid' => $_GET['id'],
            'ppt_filename' => $name.$i,
            'ppt_extension' => $pathinfo
        );

        $db::table('ppts')
            ->insert($data);

        if ($_FILES['ppt']['tmp_name']) {
            try {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ppt']['tmp_name'], DOCROOT . '/_data/ppt/' . $name . '.' . $pathinfo);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'broken';
                exit;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the PHP im using to handle the post.

```
<div class="card bg-grey">
            <h4 class="card-header bg-blue text-white text-bold">Uploads</h4>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div id="<?php echo $field_name; ?>" class="form-group <?php echo $_ERROR[$field_name] ? ' has-danger' : ''; ?>">
                    <input <?php echo ($_SESSION['level'] == 1 || $event->created_by == $_SESSION['id'] ? '' : 'readonly="readonly"'); ?> type="file" name="ppt[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""/>
                    <label>Powerpoint</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the HTML where I am submitting the file

Comment: What are you getting, rather then not getting? An `error`, or anything else? Are the file values comming through?

Comment: when I echo out the variables and $_FILES everything seems to be coming out fine. Im getting the tmp_name and other 4 parts of the array. Although It's not hitting the exception so its returning nothing

Comment: I don't know if that will actually `throw` an `error` if it fails, just put it in a `if` statement. It either needs to work or you can check if like this: `if(move_uploaded_file()){}`. Try that, and put in a debug message, I'm confident it will say it failed.